# Android studio include aar dependency

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to add ActionbarSherlock as dependency using line I got from [gradleplease](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/)

(Instead of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio) methods. At least according to [this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-intellij-projects):

"In Gradle you no longer need to add in these libraries as source code projects; you can simply refer to them as dependencies, and the build system will handle the rest; downloading, merging in resources and manifest entries, etc. For each library, look up the corresponding AAR library dependency name (provided the library in question has been updated as a android library artifact), and add these to the dependency section."

this setup should not be necessary anymore)

But it doesn't work and module settings in Android studio shows error: "Library 'ComActionbarsherlockComActionbarsherlock440.aar': Invalid classes root"

Any idea?

Comment: Could you share your build.gradle file?

Comment: Look at my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234698/how-do-i-add-guava-to-my-android-studio-project/19234870#19234870 See that I have another `respositories` in my `build.gradle` apart from the one under `buildscript`

Answer (score 0):

Add these line in your module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```