# Importing library into an Android Studio project

Tags: android

I know this has been asked like a hundred times but the solutions aren't working for me. I want to import [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) into my project. I am running `Android Studio 0.3.7`. I have tried adding it through the project structure and manually adding the files and editing the `build.gradle`. Both times it gave me the same error :

`A problem occurred evaluating project ':test'. Project with path ':libraries:PagerSlidingTabStrip:PagerSlidingTabStrip' could not be found in project ':test'.`

Since both times it gave me the same error I feel it has something to do with the library itself. How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you don't have to manually add files to `build.gradle` anymore, or at least you shouldn't. They claim that `"Add Library As..." on .jar files now works for Gradle projects; it adds in a proper dependency in the build.gradle file` - http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio037released

Comment: By the way, have you seen my question? (I asked it before AS 0.3.7 was available). Perhaps it could be of some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234698/how-do-i-add-guava-to-my-android-studio-project

Comment: I don't have a .jar file though. Just the source for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! Also I was struggled into while several days.
I solve this problem and solve it by using this way.

please follow this guide line.
[How to import external library in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342375/how-to-import-external-library-in-android-studio)

after finish your steps, just go to PagerSlidingTapStrip module -> src -> AndroidMenifest.xml

then just add 1 line

then all of things go well. If you have other question, commnet here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it! Or did I.. I am really unsure as to what is going on here but I will explain what I did anyway... Just in case someone else going through this.

So when I went to add my library in project structure this is what I saw (ignore the error for now, you shouldn't see it):
[image: My project structure page]

This is not what you should be seeing. Anyway I tried adding in dependencies but it did not work. It would just create a folder inside my project but not do anything with it. I couldn't find anywhere to delete that folder so I went and did it manually through explorer. After I came back and tried to `make` it gave me an error saying it couldn't find the folder I deleted. I restarted Android Studio and went back in to Android Structure to be greeted with a very similar error (instead it was saying it couldn't find the folder). I clicked on the go to source and it took me to the ACTUAL project structure page:

[image: Actual project structure page]

I feel like I might have done something stupid to cause this but I can't get back into those settings again... but on the bright side my library is added.