# Error:Failed to find: com.google.guava:guava:18.0.+

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, guava

I added this dependency to the gradle file

// This is used by the Google HTTP client library.

```
compile(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0.+')
```

I tried syncing the Gradle file but it keeps giving me this error

Error:Failed to find: com.google.guava:guava:18.0.+

Comment: Guava's version is only major and minor. So either fixed version: '18.0' or a range version: '18.+'. I tried both and they worked.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19340520/1881611

Answer (score 10):

It is because guava does not have a 'patch' version, only 'major' and 'minor' versions.

Try this instead:

```
compile(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0')
```

For future reference, you can search for your library's available versions by going to Maven Central:
http://search.maven.org/

Here is the info for your Guava library:
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.guava%7Cguava%7C18.0%7Cbundle